# Bulk insert bugs into bugzilla from another Bug tracker

Tags: perl, bulk, bugzilla

I am looking for a script and/or examples of scripts for bulk importing/inserting bugs into a new installation of bugzilla 4.

We are moving from an old DevTrack and need all our bugs inserted.

Our old system is MS SQL based, and I see all the bugs.

The only think I could find on the web is this API frmo Bugzilla (I assume I need to write a perl script and run it on the Bugzilla system -  http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Migrate.html

- udpate: search on google with the words: import bugs to bugzilla - returned some helpful answers. Will see if that solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 other ways I have used in the past. Either create a valid Bugzilla XML document and import it with importxml.pl http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/importxml.html

Or use email_in.pl http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/email_in.html

Bugzilla XML allows you to specify a lot of details, but is more complicated. Using email_in.pl only allows you to import a subset of the fields, but it may be sufficient and is much easier.